# Script randomly cuts off

Tags: php

I've made a VERY basic website which takes an array of image URLs, zips them, and returns the zip location. The problem is that the script cuts off at some point.

One of the following usually happens:

- not all the pictures are copied
- not all pictures are copied and the last picture has 0 file size
- sometimes the ajax call doesn't run the error or success callback

Is this because the server is only allowing a certain amount of time for the script to execute? It does seem to work with less pictures. What can I do?

I have the following settings:

max_execution_time  10  10
max_file_uploads    20  20
max_input_nesting_level 64  64
max_input_time  10

also, set_time_limit is disabled.

I tried ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); and nothing changed

edit: Probably a REALLY stupid question, but would it change anything if I executed another PHP page after a certain amount of time if the script isn't going to finish before the limit?

Comment: look into your error log to see if there is any errors about execution time or memory getting exhausted. Search the error message on StackOverflow. If there is no results, update your question with the error message.

Comment: Where's the error log? Sorry for teh noob question. I use 000webhost, I can't find anything

Comment: The [error log](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log) is the location to which PHP writes any errors that occur during script execution.

Comment: How do I view them? I'm very bad with this stuff

Comment: The same you view any other text file. If you dont have shell access on the machine, you can also try to `file_get_contents` the log file to display it in your browser.

Comment: The file is called error_log, but I just don't know what to put for its location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could do with looking at your code, but if it is simply a case of the script timing out, you can use this line:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

...to remove the time limit, and allow the script to execute completely in it's own time. You should call this as soon as you have validated the request, before you start the image copy/zip process.

If you post some code in the question I will update my answer further.

Comment: How do you mean? Is there already no time limit, or are you not allowed to set it?

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you can try:

1. Increase the execution time limit with [`set_time_limit`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php).
2. Run the script through php.exe (as a console script) and not through a web server; in this scenario, there is no time limit by default.